# Can part of the android app compile at lower API while other part compile at high level?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I am developing an app using android support library v7 whose lowest compile api is 15. However, I want to use a IPCamera control SDK provide by other in my app but I found that the SDk can only be run at API level lower than 11. I am in the same situation as this post:

[JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale local reference 0xbc00021 (index 8 in a table of size 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765776/jni-error-app-bug-accessed-stale-local-reference-0xbc00021-index-8-in-a-tabl)

My problem is this:

[JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale local reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31515713/jni-error-app-bug-accessed-stale-local-reference)

I contact the camera company, they said they have stop support this SDK and they refuse to provide me the source code of the jni to let me modify by myself. So what I think is whether I can compile the video play part using lower level API while compile the rest part using high level API? Or how can I avoid this at the error at the Java level? Thank you for reply.

Comment: _"I am developing an app using android support library v7 whose lowest compile api is 15."_ Um, what? The v7 support libraries can be used from API level 7 and up, hence the name _v7_.

Comment: @Michael I use the recyclerView and I just read this: NOTE: Using this support library requires that your app have its Target Android Version (targetSdkVersion) set to Lollipop (5.0 - API Level 21) or higher, or you will have aapt related compile errors.  You can still set the Target Framework which your app is compiled against as low as Android 4.0.3 (API Level 15).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in the manifest file

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer"
          android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
          android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

For more info about that see [uses-sdk](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html).

Comment: No, not working. I have to set the targetSDK to 21 to run support library v7, but this will lead the video play crush.

Comment: @Coroner_Rex, try the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465049/changing-api-level-android-studio